# Does sort function consider the leaf nodes in a multilevel array?

Tags: php, sorting, shuffle

This following piece of code is meant to create a multilevel array, print it, then shuffle it, again print it, and sort the array.

```
$arr=array(
        array(
            array('a','b','c')
        ),
        array(
            array('d','e','f')
        ),
    array(
            array('g','h','i')
        ),
);
print_r($arr);
shuffle($arr);
print_r($arr);
sort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Now the odd thing that i observed, when `shuffle()` is used, it only shuffles the indexes of the array that is being shuffled, it doesnt shuffle, the inner most elements `a,b,c` to something else, but when the the `sort()` function is used, it sorts back the array into the normal status and **the leaf nodes are back to alphabetical order**. Why does this happen?

**Here is the sample output:**
**Original Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                    [2] => c
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => d
                    [1] => e
                    [2] => f
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => g
                    [1] => h
                    [2] => i
                )
        )
)
```

**Shuffled Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => g
                    [1] => h
                    [2] => i
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                    [2] => c
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => d
                    [1] => e
                    [2] => f
                )
        )
)
```

**Sorted Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                    [2] => c
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => d
                    [1] => e
                    [2] => f
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => g
                    [1] => h
                    [2] => i
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the array section of PHP's [comparison operator reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), especially the array comparison transcription. Basically PHP first compares the amount of keys in the array, then checks if the arrays have the same keys (in this case, `0` for the inner arrays) and then compares the values. Because you have a nested array there, it proceeds to compare the leaf nodes in `sort()`, which leads to the array being sorted in this case by the first value of the leaf arrays (`a`, `d` and `g`).

`shuffle()` simply reorders the indexes of the array you give it regardless of what the array contains, thus it does not touch the inner arrays at all.